# Ngrx Entity, how define actions and how properly name actions with effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I have generated actions using ngrx schematics and It looks like this:

```
export enum UserActionTypes {
    LoadUsers = '[User] Load Users',
    AddUser = '[User] Add User',
    UpsertUser = '[User] Upsert User',
    AddUsers = '[User] Add Users',
    UpsertUsers = '[User] Upsert Users',
    UpdateUser = '[User] Update User',
}
```

and reducer like this:

```
case PricingActionTypes.AddPricing: {
    return adapter.addOne(action.payload.pricing, state);
}

case PricingActionTypes.UpsertPricing: {
    return adapter.upsertOne(action.payload.pricing, state);
}

case PricingActionTypes.AddPricings: {
    return adapter.addMany(action.payload.pricings, state);
}
```

My question is how to combine that with effects and call to REST API.

Should I generate actions like:

LoadUsers - which effect gets list of Users from REST API and if that api call has success status it dispatch action LoadUsersSuccess which actually add list of users to store object?

Or maybe it should looks different?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how you're describing it.

In your application you will dispatch a **Load** action, your effect will call the API and dispatch a **LoadSuccess** or **LoadFailed** action with the entities as payload.

You could also take a look at [ngrx-data](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data)

> Zero Ngrx Boilerplate
>   You may never write an action, reducer, selector, effect, or HTTP dataservice again.
>   Ngrx-data is an ngrx extension that offers a gentle introduction to ngrx/redux without the boilerplate.